# Check if given functions are continuous in topology.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have two topologies: standard and:

Topology on $X$, which is a linearly ordered space.
$T = \{ A \subset X, \forall _{x,y \in} (x \in A  \wedge x \leq y )   \Rightarrow y \in A\}$.

Check if functions: $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = xmod2,h(x) = \left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor $ are continuous in given topologies.

I started with standard topology, i already proved continous for $f$.

Is it enough for $h$ function to give a counterexample: we have a interval (0,1), which is open, and $h^{-1}[(0,1)] = \{0\}$, which is closed. So it is not continuous.

Then I have $g$ functions. It is not continous but i'm not sure how to show this. I have: $g^{-1}[(a,b)] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}, xmod2 \in (a,b) \}$. Is it true that  $g^{-1}[(0,1)] = (0,1) \cup (1,2) ] cup (2,3) ...$ ? But set is open, and function is not continuous, so something is wrong.

I have problems with topology $T$, can someone explain me on example of one of given functions how to prove continuity in this topology?

Edit:
Or maybe for $g$ wil be better to take $(0,1/2)$ then $g^{-1} = (0,1/2] \cup (1,3/2] ...$, set is closed, so function is not continuous.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous in $T$, take the set $(1,\infty)$, this set is open, but $f^{-1}((1,\infty))=(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)=B$ is not, since $-2\in B$ but $-1\notin B$ and $-1\geq-2$.

Comment: also, what is your definition of $xmod2$?

Comment: $xmod2 = x - 2\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\right \rfloor $

Comment: In that case $g$ is not continuous since $g([0,2])=[0,2)$, and the image of a compact set by a continuous function must be compact